# How to filter tcpdump for the direct hostname of a website?

Tags: networking, wireshark, tcpdump

As mentioned in the title, I want to get the direct hostname when visiting a website using my PC.

For example, visiting www.youtube.com, at the back it would go to many more domain like fonts.gstatic.com, www.google.com etc...

I would like to only capture the website that I key into the browser (e.g www.youtube.com only) without the underlying routing of website. Is this possible through tcpdump?

The filter I'm using right now is

```
tcpdump -l -n -i eth0 dst port 53
```

Comment: Seems like the best I can get is only all the DNS request. I am also thinking that this is impossible as it violates the nature of packets, you shouldn't be able to know which are the first packet that are being sent from your own device when visiting different website..hmm